# selector state_enabled=false not working

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a simple selector for a TextView:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/darkgray" />
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@color/background_red_down" />
 <item android:drawable="@color/background_red" />
```

I am using MVVMCross do the textview Enabled property is binded to a property:

```
 <TextView
            local:MvxBind="Click RecomendDishViewModel.SendCommand;                        
                            Enabled RecomendDishViewModel.IsSendPostEnabled"
            android:text="@string/SendLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SendButton"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_red_button_background"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:enabled="false" />
```

The Pressed state works perfectly but the enabled=false state is partially working, it is in fact disabled, as pressing on it does nothing, but it still stays in red color. The funny thing is that when I set android:enabled="false"  I can see it turn to gray in the desiger.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Amit